# MIME types not showing in OS X 10.5.8

Tags: macos, coffeescript, mime-types

I'm trying to upload a csv file through a form but am running into issues on Mac OS X 10.5.8.
Here's the relevant piece of code:

```
template = Handlebars.compile '''
<form action="/dashboard/csv-upload/" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" class="csv-upload">
 <p>
   <label for="id_uploaded_file" style="float:left;">Upload a CSV file:</label>
   <input class="span2" name="uploaded_file" id="id_uploaded_file" type="file">
 </p>
</form>
'''

class exports.uploadController extends Backbone.View
  el: '#main-container'

  events:
    'submit form.csv-upload' : '_csvUpload'

  initialize: () =>
    @render()

  render: () =>
    return @ if @isRendered
    @isRendered = true

  _csvUpload : (e) =>
    e.preventDefault()
    file = @$('#id_uploaded_file')[0].files[0]
    if not file
        alert "Please select a file to upload, first."
        return false
    console.log(file.type)
    if file.type != "text/csv" and file.type != "text/plain"
        alert "Please upload a CSV or TXT file"
        return false
```

The problem I'm running into is that I get the "Please upload a CSV or TXT file" error on Mac OS X 10.5.8 even if I upload a .csv file. The console.log returns a blank string. Here's a screenshot:
[image: error screenshot]

I've tried searching on Google, but haven't found anything. I have also tried this with both Safari and  Chrome. Do File objects not have exhibit a type property on OS X 10.5.8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my (Windows) system .csv files are mapped to the "application/vnd.ms-excel" MIME type, so this code would also fail on my computer. On Windows, the mime types are filled in based on the default application the user has set, which is mapped to the registry keys in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MIME\Database\Content Type . Unrecognized file types come back with type="" (as you have seen). [It looks like things behave similarly in OSX](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1574524?start=0&tstart=0)

I think your best bet is to just check if the file ends in ".csv". Then your server side code can check whether it is a valid csv file and return an error if it's not.